# Project Euler #2 Java

Tags: java, for-loop, fibonacci

**prompt:**

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

**My Code:**

```
public class EvenFibonaccinumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 4000000; i += (i - 1)) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    }
}
```

**ISSUE: Eclipse console remains blank**

Comment: It doesn't? Have you tried fixing it?

Comment: So your code [doesn't work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: ^@ShivPatel such comments don't help you. If you are not familiar with what Stack Overflow is for and how to ask questions here please visit [tour] and our  [help], especially ["how do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Also ["Stack Overflow question checklist"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) is quite handy.

Comment: I think you should edit the title of your question. Maybe your "ISSUE: Eclipse console remains blank" could be the title? I think the down-votes are a little harsh

Comment: @wfunston down-votes ware cast based on [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40061961/1) of this question, where only description of problem given by OP was "does not work". While OP improved it later, not everyone who cast these votes earlier are still here to retrieve them.

Comment: My apologizes I am new to this site. But god damn some people are rude here.

Comment: Many people are misunderstanding purpose of Stack Overflow. We are not here *to* answer questions, but to *build repository* of specific programming question-answers which others could use to search and find solutions for their programming problems (so lets not confuse *goal* with *way of achieving it*). But, to make it possible, questions must contain at least minimal description of problem which OP is facing. "Doesn't work" is too general. It is like telling a doctor you feel sick and nothing more. Such questions tends to irritate people (and it is hard to blame them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because of an infinite loop...

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4000000; i += (i - 1)) {
    // first iteration: i = 1
    // (i - 1) = (1 - 1) = 0: therefore i += 0
    // i always = 1
}
```